# Palindrome Pairs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, palindrome

**The task**

is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-pairs/)

> Given a list of unique words, find all pairs of distinct indices (i,
>   j) in the given list, so that the concatenation of the two words, i.e.
>   words[i] + words[j] is a palindrome.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> Input: ["abcd","dcba","lls","s","sssll"]
>
> Output: [[0,1],[1,0],[3,2],[2,4]]
>
> Explanation: The palindromes are
>   ["dcbaabcd","abcddcba","slls","llssssll"]
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> Input: ["bat","tab","cat"]
>
> Output: [[0,1],[1,0]]
>
> Explanation: The palindromes are ["battab","tabbat"]

**My solution**

```
/**
 * @param {string[]} words
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
var palindromePairs = function(words) {
  const index = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
      if (i !== j) {
        if (isPalindrome(words[i] + words[j])) { index.push([i, j]); }
      }      
    }
  }
  return index;
};

const isPalindrome = (word) => {
  const len = word.length / 2 + 1;
  const wordLength = word.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (word[i] !== word[wordLength - i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: `isPalindrome` can be a one-liner with `return word === word.split("").reverse().join("");`, which means that you can actually inline the check inside of `palindromPairs`

Comment: @ChatterOne: I know, but it's too slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, at a very high level, let me say that I find the implementation straightforward to read and easy to verify correct.

---

> ```
> /**
>  * @param {string[]} words
>  * @return {number[][]}
>  */
> ```

Given the context and the fact that the code is essentially use-and-throw-away, I can understand why you didn't provide more documentation than this for `palindromePairs`. I'm not sure, though, why there isn't corresponding documentation for `isPalindrome`, which is almost certainly reusable.

---

> ```
> var palindromePairs = function(words) {
> ```

> ```
> const isPalindrome = (word) => {
> ```

Why is one `var` and one `const`?

---

> ```
>       if (i !== j) {
>         if (isPalindrome(words[i] + words[j])) { index.push([i, j]); }
>       }
> ```

I would prefer a single condition instead of an extra layer of indentation:

```
      if (i !== j && isPalindrome(words[i] + words[j])) {
        index.push([i, j]);
      }
```

---

> ```
>   const len = word.length / 2 + 1;
>   const wordLength = word.length - 1;
> ```

I don't find these names helpful - particularly the second one, for which I would prefer something like `lastIndex`. Alternatively it can be written with two indices as

```
  for (let i = 0, j = word.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if (word[i] !== word[j]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

---

Having said all that: why was this exercise in leetcode? I suspect that the intention was to push you to a more sophisticated algorithm than this one, which is brute force. It might be a valuable exercise for you to see whether you can find a more efficient solution, perhaps using trees of some kind...

Comment: That's true. It's not optimal. But based on my skills right now, it's currently the best I could come up within an hour. Thanks for your input.